# Nucleus in the wires

Tags: physical-chemistry

Can someone explain why we consider the electrons to move through a wire and not the nucleus? Couldnt atoms get ionised with losing a proton?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how metallic bonding works? There are metal nuclei in a sea of free electrons. These electrons are the ones responsible for conduction.

Even in a chemical reaction, no atom gets ionized by losing a proton. Losing a proton will change the compound itself and should require huge energy.